# SQL: como copiar o valor de uma meta_key em um array em outra meta_key?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

*Perguntando aqui pois parece mais uma questão de SQL do que Wordpress.*

Tenho uma instalação de WordPress que usa campos personalizados tanto do plugin ACF quanto do template. São mais de mil posts usando o campo "subtitle" do plugin - os campos do template estão vazios.

Agora preciso migrar todos os valores desses campos para os campos do próprio template, chamados "td_subtitle". Vi uma resposta de como fazer isso com SQL:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'subtitle' where meta_key = 'td_subtitle';
```

Mas conferindo o banco de dados, o valor de "td_subtitle" fica dentro de um array, assim:

```
a:1:{s:11:"td_subtitle";s:24:"Subtítulo de um post blablabla";}
```

O "td_subtitle" na verdade fica em dentro do  meta_key "td_post_theme_settings", que tem outros valores além dele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pergunta**: como mover os valores do meta_key subtitle para o td_post_theme_settings > td_subtitle?

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de fazer isso, talvez não seja a mais eficiente, mas que atenderia a demanda, seria..

**Antes de mais nada, tenha *backup* de tudo!**

adicionar uma função no arquivo `functions.php` do seu tema, que será disparada assim q o primeiro acesso ao site for realizado, restringindo ao usuário admin (pelo menos). É possível adicionar outras verificações para evitar duplicidades e acessos indevidos.

Nessa função, você pode percorrer os *posts*, e usando a função `$old_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'subtitle' )` pegar o dado antigo e com a função `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'td_subtitle', $old_value )` salvar no *meta* correto.

Isso, considerando que essas duas funções sejam suficientes para acessar e salvar os dados que precisa manipular.